# Android Grouped TextView

Tags: android, android-edittext

My Android application has a form that the user has to fill in. I was looking for something like this. This http://img688.imageshack.us/img688/4162/photocr.jpg. I mean where the Edit Text look neat like this. Any suggestions on how we can replicate this in Android. I have seen a couple of Applications in Android that have a UI like this. Any suggestions will be welcome.

Kind Regards,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/round_linearlayout"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/first_name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/first_name_hint_text"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#778BB0"
        android:textColorHint="#778BB0"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/last_name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/last_name_hint_text"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#778BB0"
        android:textColorHint="#778BB0"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email_address"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/email_address_hint_text"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#778BB0"
        android:textColorHint="#778BB0"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/password_hint_text"
       android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#778BB0"
        android:textColorHint="#778BB0"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/already_have_an_account"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="@string/already_have_an_account"
        android:textColor="@color/hyperlink" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edited the answer to what you want.

```
public class EditTextView extends LinearLayout{

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private EditText edit_text;
    private TextView item;
    private View spacer;

    public EditTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        initialize();
    }

    public void setLabel(String label){
        item.setText(label);
    }

    public void setText(String text){
        item.setText(text);
    }

    public String getText(){
        if((edit_text != null)&& (edit_text.getText() != null)){
            return edit_text.getText().toString();          
        }
        return "";
    }

    public void showSpacer(){
        spacer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    private void initialize() {
         inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_text_view, this);
         edit_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
         item = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_label);
         spacer = (View) findViewById(R.id.spacer);
         spacer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }


}
```

Used to get text as follows

```
EditTextView textView = (EditTextView) groupedView2.getFieldViewAt(0);
System.out.println(textView.getText());
textView = (EditTextView) groupedView2.getFieldViewAt(1);
System.out.println(textView.getText());
```

This works for me very well. Let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: Why people think that apple-style naming is good for everything? :'(

Comment: @Jin35. I must agree with you. But sometimes its what the customer wants. Though we explain android specific layouts and styles. No customer prefers it though. :(...

Comment: I have had a look at this. But this only gives you a Static ListView not an EditText . I want the user to be able to type into this. I came across this example http://vladexologija.blogspot.com/2012/03/groupedtextview.html. The problem with this is that  i can type into the box but not retrieve it ?

Comment: @user365019 edited the answer for what you want. Accept if it gets fixed for you.

Answer (score 3):

It's easy what you want to achieve with android. You just need to use shape drawables for your edit texts.

Here is how you can achieve this:

**shape drawables** 
 drawable for upper edit text

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid 
        android:color="#ffffff"/>
    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:topRightRadius="15dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"/>

</shape>
```

drwable for lower edit text

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid 
        android:color="#ffffff"/>
    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
        android:topRightRadius="0dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"/>

</shape>
```

XML for the layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#3434ff"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="50dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@drawable/stack"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/emailEdt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_back1"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#5a5a5a" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/passwordEdt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_back2"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The resulting layout will be like this:
[image]

Comment: How do i add a row in between these ?

Comment: For adding a row in between just add an edit text in between and create a new shape drawable for its background. For creating the shape drawable you can refer to the above code but you need to make few changes. For the in-between rows there should not be any rounded corner.So, either remove the cornet attribute from the shape drawable or set its radius to be 0dp

Answer (score -1):

You can have a LinearLayout,appy `border.xml` as drawable background to that LinearLayout this:

**border.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/grey"/>
<!-- "#5D2E8C"  -->
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />       <!-- background to the border -->
    <padding
        android:bottom="2dp"
        android:left="2dp"
        android:right="2dp"
        android:top="2dp" />
    <corners android:radius="20dp" />

</shape>
```

1. Input in it a EditText view for Username
2. A TextView with width fill_parent and height=1dp and background
   color   as black(this will Give you the line like feel)
3. An EditText view for Password.

**//=========================Edit=================================//**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/first_name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/first_name_hint_text"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#778BB0"
        android:textColorHint="#778BB0"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <View 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/last_name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/last_name_hint_text"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#778BB0"
        android:textColorHint="#778BB0"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
<View 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        />
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/email_address"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/email_address_hint_text"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#778BB0"
        android:textColorHint="#778BB0"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
<View 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/password_hint_text"
       android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#778BB0"
        android:textColorHint="#778BB0"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
<View 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/already_have_an_account"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="@string/already_have_an_account"
        android:textColor="@color/red1" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I tried this. Still not the right type. Can anyone show me an exmaple of a good android standard Input Form ?

Comment: Not working means??What's the problem in this??can you tell me the problem..i will solve for you

Comment: Can you see my edited question. I have placed my code there .

Comment: What i was trying to say was the above code which is pretty simple to understand...Please check it Once and Give me feedback for my Efforts...Regards.

Comment: Copy and paste the border.xml code with the same file name in your drawable folder

Comment: I have used it my project..It gives the layout a round shape..Have you tried it..plz let me know the problem you are facing using this?